# JavaScript function works only on Windows machine

Tags: javascript, windows, macos

I am working on a project on my Windows computer as well on my Macbook. I got a function that register components defined in certain directories globally like this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

/**
 * Third-party imports.
 */
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst';
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

/**
 * Register components from the ./components and ./components/core
 * directories. This way these components don't have to be imported
 * manually every time.
 *
 * The core components are the core of other components and contains
 * alerts, notifications, input fields etc.
 *
 * Base components are bigger components made upon the core components
 * and contain a combination of one or more of the core components. These
 * are usually components that contain a lot of code and have to be re-used
 * across the whole application.
 *
 * @param {Vue instance} app
 */
function registerGlobalComponents (app) {
  const requireComponent = require.context(
    './components' || './components/core' || './components/base',
    true,
    /\.vue$/
  );

  for (const file of requireComponent.keys()) {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(file);
    const name = file
      .replace(/index.js/, '')
      .replace(/^\.\//, '')
      .replace(/\.\w+$/, '');
    const componentName = upperFirst(camelCase(name));

    app.component(componentName,
      componentConfig.default);
  }
}

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {

        const inertiaApp = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) });

        inertiaApp.use(plugin);
        inertiaApp.mixin({ methods: { route } })
        registerGlobalComponents(inertiaApp);
        inertiaApp.mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

When I run `npm run watch` or `dev` or `prod` it compiles the code and successfully shows me the website on my Windows machine. But when I do this on my Macbook it throws the following error:

> Can't resolve './components' in '/Users/bas/Sites/trainfit/resources/js'

Is there a reason why this works on a Windows machine but not on a machine that runs on MacOS?

Some more information about my project:

- Made with Vue and Inertiajs
- Running this code from Visual Studio Code

Comment: Your code doesn't look complete. What are the `require` and `requireComponent` objects? What do you mean by running in Windows/MacOS? Are your running in Node, in a browser, or what? Did you miss out some additional tags?

Comment: Is the folder structure the same on Windows and MacOS?

Comment: @CascadiaJS the folder structure of my project is the same. However the paths of the project on the machines are different. MacOS `/var/www/Sites/projectname` and Windows `D://laragon/www/projectname`.

Comment: Can't resolve error means, `file not found` error

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [docs](https://create-react-app.de), you start by creating a jsconfig.json file in your root with these characters and symbols in it:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

You can find examples and references here : - [here](https://medium.com/hackernoon/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4c6cfb66c35d)

Comment: I will try your answer when I am at home tonight, i'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: Yes please, Pls refer above blog at once. 